# Re-formatting the same string doesn't work. How can I achieve this?

Tags: python

I want to populate a base string in a loop, to access files with increasing calendar days in their name. This is the cut down version:

```
my_str = "filename_{}_blah.txt"
for n in range(3):
    my_str = my_str.format(n)
    print(my_str)
```

Output:

```
filename_0_blah.txt
filename_0_blah.txt
filename_0_blah.txt
```

I expected the numbers to increase.

(1) Is there a way around this,

(2) Why does this happen?

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use a different variable to hold the format string and result. If you assign back to the same variable, it no longer contains the format string, the `{}` has been replaced with the value of `n`. So the next time, there's no placeholder to replace with the next value of `n`.

```
format_str = "filename_{}_blah.txt"
for n in range(3):
    my_str = format_str.format(n)
    print(my_str)
```

Comment: ahh....right. format should probably raise an error if there's no {".."} in the string to substitute with. Or is there a reason for that?

Comment: You'll get an error if there are too few arguments, because it tries to access outside the argument tuple, but not if there are more arguments than placeholders.

Answer (score 4):

(1) Yes there is

```py
for n in range(3):
    my_str = "filename_{}_blah.txt".format(n)
    print(my_str)
```

(2) This happens because you already filled the `{}` in the string in the first iteration, so after that iteration the `my_str` actually becomes `filename_0_blah.txt` and there is nothing to format in it

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
my_str = "filename_{}_blah.txt"
for n in range(3):
    print(my_str.format(n));
```

Comment: @Dv06 Use the code formatting next time. You can achieve this by using the {}-Button.

Answer (score 1):

As @Barmar has said, the problem in your code is that the variable `my_str = "filename_{}_blah.txt"` is changed to `filename_0_blan.txt` in the very first loop. So the code `my_str.format(n)` can do nothing afterwards.

I want to add a new solution which is available after python3.6:

```
for n in range(3):
    my_str = f'filename_{n}_blah.txt'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
my_str = 'filename_{}_blah.txt'
str_list=[]
for n in range(3):
    str_list.append(my_str.format(n))
    print(str_list[n])
```

This gives your expected output. Hope it helps :)